# How can I do what the trigger does with the stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger on my `tbl_permissions` table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_permissions] 
ON [dbo].[tbl_permissions]
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
    IF (UPDATE(email) OR UPDATE(gsm))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_permissions_log (customer_id, type, email_new_value, email_old_value, gsm_new_value, gsm_oldu_value, modify_user_id, modify_date)
            SELECT 
                i.customer_id, 
                d.type, i.email, d.email,
                i.gsm, d.gsm,
                i.modify_user_id, GETDATE() 
            FROM 
                inserted i, deleted d, dbo.tbl_permissions c
            WHERE 
                c.pk_id = i.pk_id 
                AND c.pk_id = d.pk_id 
                AND (RTRIM(d.email) <> RTRIM(i.email)
                     OR (RTRIM(d.gsm) <> RTRIM(i.gsm)))
```

The trigger is triggered in 2 stored procedures:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_activation_email_update]
    (@sEmail NVARCHAR(100),
     @lModifyUserId INT,
     @bEML  BIT)         
AS  
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.tbl_permissions  
    SET email = @bEML,
        modify_user_id = @lModifyUserId,
        modify_date = GETDATE()      
    WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id 
                          FROM dbo.tbl_contact_info 
                          WHERE email = @sEmail)
END
```

and:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_activation_sms_update]
    (@sGsmNo NVARCHAR(15),
     @lModifyUserId INT,
     @bGsm BIT)      
AS  
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.tbl_permissions  
    SET gsm = @bGsm,
        modify_user_id = @lModifyUserId,
        modify_date = GETDATE()      
    WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id 
                          FROM dbo.tbl_contact_info 
                          WHERE gsm_no = RIGHT(@sGsmNo, 10))
END
```

I want to remove trigger because of performance problem. So how can I perform the work of the trigger in the stored procedures?

I tried the call another stored procedure inside update stored procedures and perform operations in the this new stored procedure but I can't.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Also, the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: *"The trigger is triggering in 2 store procedure."* this doesn't make sense. A `TRIGGER` doesn't get triggered in a stored procedure. Your `TRIGGER`, `dbo.trig_permissions` is *triggered* when a `UPDATE` occurs on the table `dbo.tbl_permissions`; if either of those procedures were used or not is *irrelevant*.

Comment: *"I want to remove trigger because of performance problem"* why not fix the trigger? There is no need for the `TRIGGEr` to reference `dbo.tbl_permissions` in the `FROM`; just the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables is fine, as a row cannot appear and not the other in an `UPDATE`. Also, why are you wrapping `RTRIM` functions around the columns in the `WHERE`? This *will* cause performance issuse and is *completely pointless*; trailing spaces are **ignored** for comparison purposes. `'abc' = 'abc ' = 'abc   ' = 'abc       '`.

Comment: As well as the removing the unnecessary reference to `dbo.tbl_permissions`, you may find changing the equality operator from `i.email <> d.email OR i.gsm <>d.gsm` to `NOT EXISTS (SELECT i.Email, i.gsm INTERSECT SELECT d.Email, d.gsm)` helps improve performace. More on this here:  [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html)

Comment: Also keep in mind that the UPDATE function in your trigger does not care if the value actually changed. It will return true if the column is in the update statement. So it will fire if you set the new value to the same as the old value. This other question would be worth reading at some point as well. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedures, you can use the OUTPUT clause to capture data from the UPDATE statement, and then use that captured data to insert rows into the log table.

Something like the following:

```
DECLARE @Updated TABLE (pk_id int, newEmail, oldEmail, modify_user_id int)

UPDATE dbo.tbl_permissions
SET email=@bEML,
    modify_user_id=@lModifyUserId,
    modify_date=GETDATE()
OUTPUT inserted.pk_id, inserted.email, deleted.email, u.modify_user_id
    INTO @Updated 
WHERE customer_id 
    IN(SELECT  customer_id FROM dbo.tbl_contact_info WHERE email=@sEmail)

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_permissions_log 
   (customer_id,type,email_new_value,email_old_value,gsm_new_value,gsm_oldu_value,modify_user_id,modify_date)
SELECT 
    p.customer_id, 
    p.type,
    u.newEmail,
    u.oldEmail,
    p.gsm,
    p.gsm,
    u.modify_user_id,
    GETDATE()   
FROM @Updated u
JOIN dbo.tbl_permissions p ON p.pk_id = u.pk_id
WHERE u.newEmail <> u.oldEmail
```

You can also direct output directly into the log table, but the statement is getting pretty cluttered at that point.

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl_permissions
SET email=@bEML,
    modify_user_id=@lModifyUserId,
    modify_date=GETDATE()
OUTPUT
    inserted.customer_id, 
    inserted.type,
    inserted.email,
    deleted.email,
    inserted.gsm,
    deleted.gsm,
    inserted.modify_user_id,
    GETDATE()   
    INTO dbo.tbl_permissions_log 
        (customer_id,type,email_new_value,email_old_value,gsm_new_value,gsm_oldu_value,modify_user_id,modify_date)
WHERE customer_id 
    IN(SELECT  customer_id FROM dbo.tbl_contact_info WHERE email=@sEmail)
AND email <> @bEML
```

In both cases we limit the log insert to cases where the updated value actually changed. In the latter case, this necessitates applying that condition to the actual update statement. This would modify the original behavior by also inhibiting the update to modify_user_id and modify_date when email is unchanged. (This might be a positive change.)